# I'm keep getting this error while running my flutter app and my console is full of it

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, mobile-application

```
E/UIFirst ( 4290): failed to open /proc/4290/stuck_info, No such file or directory
```

**more than 100 times in console**
...

Comment: are you running your app on a physical device ?

Comment: Here is related github issue - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64152 Looks like flutter team can't solve it for now

Comment: Yes @FahmiSawalha

Comment: Thanks @Mol0ko but seen it already with no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Drony-Rajarwal this has been a confirmed problem using i think oppo phones or REALME with android 10 , you have no choice except downgrading or using a emulator device , according to this :
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55542

the problem was solved by updating the device .

Comment: Thank You. This was very helpful. I was always wondering why only I'm getting this error and not other flutter developers in my circle. xD

Comment: this problem with the realme/oppo phone... but I solved this by selecting my app in select debug app option of phone